# custom sort in java based on sql query values

Tags: java, sql

I have a query in java fetching various columns and values like

```
 apple | banana | orange | kiwi | tomato
---------------------------------------------
 raw   | ripped | fresh  |  old | expired

in to rows
-----------------
fruits | status
----------------
apple  | raw
banana | ripped
orange | fresh
kiwi   | old
tamato | expired
```

Now I would like to **sort them in order** like mentioned below in JAVA after fetching values from SQL with out sort.

```
----------------------------

fruits | status
----------------
orange | fresh
banana | ripped
apple  | raw
kiwi   | old
tamato | expired
```

Sort by Status in the above mentioned order.
I am looking for java code.

String query = "select **** "

ps = con.prepareStatement(query);

String status="";
rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next()){

/* LOGIC TO SORT AS PER THE STATUS */

}

Comment: Good luck with that! On a serious note, what's the question

Comment: Can you check now please @AndrewL.

Comment: I still don't see a question

Comment: What is the sorting logic? Is it a sort by "freshness" status? By fruit color? By size of fruit? Random? Does "[ripped](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ripped)" mean "[ripened](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ripen)"?

Comment: This question deservers an oscar (I can call it as heighest award in technology )

Comment: does it makes sense now ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add StatusID with Status . For Example

### fruits | status | statusID

orange | fresh   | 1
banana | ripped  | 2
apple  | raw     | 3
kiwi   | old     | 4
tamato | expired | 5

You can assign ID based on fruit Freshess level

Comment: Thanks for this but How would I code a Java even If  I have the ID for each status ? I have added IDin the java for each status.